# How to compare both strings and float in compareTo

Tags: java, compareto

I am trying to compare both strings and float in the `compareTo` method  but I'm not sure what my final value is going to be.

Below is the `compareTo` method that I have implemented so far:

```
ObjectClass otherObj = (ObjectClass)o;

float f1 = this.getValue();
float f2 = otherObj.getValue();
int retValue = Float.compare(f1,f2);

String code1 = this.getCode();
String code2 = otherObj.getCode();
int retValue2 = code1.compareTo(code2);

int finalRet = ??
return finalRet;
```

if the input is

```
hashMap.put(new ObjectClass ("20030122", 0.019f), "20030122");
hashMap.put(new ObjectClass ("20030123", 0.019f), "20030123");
hashMap.put(new ObjectClass ("20030124", 0.011f), "20030124");
```

my output should be in this order

```
"20030123", 0.019f
"20030122", 0.019f
"20030124", 0.011f
```

Comment: What result do you expect? E.g. if "1.0, B" and "2.0, A" are compared, which is "less then the other" (and why)?

Comment: @Tyler : This is in Java.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch : I have added the scenario in the question that I had poseted. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your sorting rules are still unclear. The output you gave does not have any apparent order. Maybe you should clearly define your sorting rules for us and yourself, after doing that you probably see the code yourself too.

Comment: @dtech : The order is the combination of float and string comparison... First we are taking the highest float value and if there is a duplicate value available in the map for that float value we are considering the max in the key which in this case is "20030123", 0.019f...

Comment: Well you just stated it yourself, just integrate those rules into your code: `compare floats. If not equal return that value, if equal then compare strings and return that value`

Comment: @dtech, thanks for the guidance... was not thinking clearly on that... it finally worked...

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow your class to be comparable you must implement in it interface [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

When the comparison should be based on more then single class member. You compare it sequentially when result of previous was equal to zero. By sequence order you specify the final ordering.

```
class MyObject implements Comparable<MyObject> {

  String message;
  long   value;  

  @Override
  public int compareTo(MyObject that) {

     if(that == null) {
       return -1;
     }

     if(this == that) {
       return 0;
     }

     int result = this.message.compareTo(that.message);

     if(result == 0) {
        result = Long.compare(this.value,that.value);
     }

     return result;

  }

}
```

The above example will result with

```
"20030122", 0.019f
"20030123", 0.019f
"20030124", 0.011f
```

Comment: I have used comparable interface .... the problem is with the compareTo implementation... The order is the combination of float and string comparison... The output we are expecting is that First we are taking the highest float value and if there is a duplicate value available in the map for that float value we are considering the max in the key which in this case is "20030123", 0.019f... and not 20030122", 0.019f